# mySQL - sql query Multi join issue

Tags: mysql

My title is perhaps not the most explanatory.

So I'll explain my problem further.

I have four tables :

```
Category
- idCategory varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL
- idMerchant int(11) NOT NULL
- parentCategory varchar(100) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL
- level int(11) NOT NULL <-- here the data represent the level of the category
- label varchar(100) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL
- PRIMARY KEY (`idCategory`,`idMerchant`),

Product
- idProduct int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT
- idCategory varchar(100) NOT NULL
- description varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL
- label varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL
- PRIMARY KEY (`idProduct`)


ProductAttribute
- idProduct int(11) NOT NULL
- idAttribute int(11) NOT NULL
- PRIMARY KEY (`idProduct`,`idAttribute`)

Attribute
- idAttribute int(11) NOT NULL
- code varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL
- label varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL
- PRIMARY KEY (`idAttribute`)
```

My goal is to fetch data by a Category and his sub-categories. Each subcategories have their own products and finally each have multiple attibutes.

```
SELECT pc.label, pc.level, c.label as 'C_label', c.level, p.label as 'P_label', a.label as 'A_Label' 
FROM `Category` c join `Product` p using(idCategory) 
JOIN `ProductAttribute` using(idProduct) 
JOIN `Attribute` a using(idAttribute) 
JOIN (
      Select idCategory, label 
      FROM Category Where level = 1 and idMerchant = 65
) as pc 
ON c.parentCategory=pc.idCategory WHERE idMerchant = 65
```

My expection was to get a table like these:

```
label | level | C_label | level | P_label | A_Label
Boy   |     1 | Watch   |     2 |  Brand  | Festina   
...   |     1 | Watch   |     2 |  Brand  |Pequignet
...   |   ... |   ...   |   ... |    ...  |     ...
Girl  |     1 | Watch   |     2 |  Brand  |Bell & Ross
...
```

etc...

But the result is like this :

```
label | level | C_label | level | P_label | A_Label
Boy   |     1 | Watch   |     2 |   Size  |Bell & Ross
...   |     1 | Watch   |     2 |   Size  |   Burton
...   |   ... |   ...   |   ... |    ...  |Coca-Cola <-- I have some brand which are not related with the category
Girl  |     1 | Watch   |     2 |   Size  |  Swiffer <-- Other example
...
```

For this example a lot of brands are listed alphabetically but doesn't have relation with the related product. But for some attributes sometimes, the attributes are obvious with the product, like TV which list only the resolution.

So can you tell me why query is not correct.

Thanks.

Comment: This sounds more like a problem with the data than with the query.  For instance, despite the column names, perhaps you have composite primary keys on the one or more reference tables or unexpected values in the tables.

Comment: @GordonLinoff is it the usage of ' in aliases?

Comment: @fortune . . . No, that is just a bad practice.  But if the query runs, then aliases defined with single quotes in the `select` clause would not affect the results.

Comment: @GordonLinoff You learned me something about single quotes uses and aliases, i'll not use them for my next query. Two tables have composite primary keys, but I don't how it can help me to manage the datas. The database engine is MyISAM, which, if I'm not wrong, can't use foreign keys, things I'm more comfortable with. It's why i think we can find the ProductAttribute which is composed only by primary keys to refer to Product and Attribute tables.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see how this query can not be returning an error, because I don't see any reference to the rowsource **`h`** except in this predicate:

```
ON h.parentCode=pc.idCategory 
   ^
```

I also don't see any column named **`parentCode`** in the four tables you listed column names for. I don't see the datatypes of the columns (any implicit data conversions?), any key definitions (primary keys, unique keys, foreign keys). There's insufficient information to further diagnose a problem with the query.

Sometimes, "wrong results" of the type you are reporting is an issue with the values in the tables. To diagnose this, we modify the query to include all the PRIMARY KEY columns and columns used in JOIN predicates, in the SELECT list.

Comment: My mistakes. I have corrected the missing elements.